# Pass remote user to tomcat over AJP

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ldap, kerberos

I'm using Kerberos + LDAP for authentication on Apache.  I've then created an AJP from Apache to Tomcat.

Since Apache handles the authentication, is there a way to securely pass the remote user to tomcat?

Specifically, the first thing I want to achieve is using Kerberos + LDAP from Apache over AJP to Tomcat Manager.

I'd like Tomcat to allow any user that is passed into it from Apache.

Comment: Is there any reason to do with in the frontend? One can do this perfectly in Tomcat for all users.

Answer (score 0):

It already happens. Just call `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` in your code.

Comment: With tomcat8, I had to add ` tomcatAuthentication="false"` to the AJP connector configuration.